# codeigniter ajax post value undefined error on index page

Tags: php, ajax, database, codeigniter

I'm working on the codeigniter web application I need to get users' data from the database but based on user id?

The problem is that `ajax` posting value to the index page browsers, network showing that Ajax posting value to the index page, When I try to echo or print variable on the index page.

**Index Page Showing Error After Echo leadID**

```
Notice: Undefined index: leadID and leadID = 0
```

**Index Page**

```
$addnote ="<a class='btn' data-popup-open='popup-1' href='#' 
data-id='$lead->id'>Add Note</a>";
```

**Ajax Posting**

```
    $('.btn').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

        var leadID = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var dataString = 'leadID=' + leadID; 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            dataType: 'text',
            url: "index.php",  
            data: dataString,  
            success: function(response) {


            }
        }); 
    });
```

**Database Query**

```
$leadID = intval($_POST['leadID']);
$sql = "select Note from {$dbPre}users where leadID='$leadID'";  
$exists = $db->extQueryRowObj($sql);
$displaynote = $exists->Note;
```

Comment: May be try `url: "<?php echo base_url('controllername/function');?>",` you will need to also autoload url helper and set the base_url in config.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 but how do i do with simple php ?

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you read the codeigniter user guide. For the obvious reason you wouldn't be trying to send an AJAX request to index.php... As @wolfgang suggested, you would be sending it to a controller/method...

Answer (score 1):

If you need simple php solution then try this code

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

        var leadID = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            dataType: 'text',
            url: "index.php",  
            data: {
                leadID : leadID
            }
            success: function(response) {
               alert(response);
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Now in `index.php`

```
$leadID = intval($_POST['leadID']);
$sql = 'select Note from '.$dbPre.'users where leadID='.$leadID;  
$exists = $db->extQueryRowObj($sql);
$displaynote = $exists->Note;
echo $displaynote;
```